# need help removing '[' ']' ' " ' from a csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime, replace

so i have 2 sections of code one csv writer that read and uploads information from several water quality sensors and uploads it to said csv however it writes into the csv as follows [sensor reader and csv writer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6uYr.png)

```
import csv
import os
import time
from gdx import gdx 
gdx = gdx.gdx()
gdx.open(connection='usb')   
gdx.select_sensors() 
os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\")
with open('sensor_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as my_data_file:   
    csv_writer = csv.writer(my_data_file)
    while True:
        gdx.start(period=100) 
        column_headers = gdx.enabled_sensor_info()
        csv_writer.writerow(column_headers)

        for i in range(0,100000):
            measurements = gdx.read()
            localtime = time.localtime()
            result = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", localtime)
            print(result)
            combined_rows = [result, measurements]
            csv_writer.writerow(combined_rows)
            print(measurements)
            my_data_file.flush()
            time.sleep(59.9)
```

and produces the following [csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QkgK.png)

```
DO Concentration (mg/L),DO Saturation (%),Temperature 
(�C),Pressure (kPa),DO Salinity (mg/L)
11:08:28 PM,"[0.0, 50000.0, 26.399999618530273, 
100.69999694824219, 50.0]"
11:09:28 PM,"[0.0, 50000.0, 26.399999618530273, 
100.69999694824219, 50.0]"
11:10:28 PM,"[0.0, 50000.0, 26.399999618530273, 
100.69999694824219, 50.0]"
```

however i seem to be unable to remove the double quotation marks and square brackets from the file i also need an additional column for Datetime as you can see, i am extremely new to coding and am way out of my depth any help woudl be appreciated here is the closest i got to solving it

```
df = pandas.read_csv("sensor_data.csv", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df = df.replace('\\"','', regex=True)
df = df.replace('\[','', regex=True)
df = df.replace('\]','', regex=True)
df
```

[my failed attempt at removing quotations and square brackets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/johZM.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: oh sorry, first time posting

Comment: try this line `df.replace('\"', '')`

Comment: The issue is here; `combined_rows = [result, measurements]` I'm guessing `measurements = gdx.read()` is returning a list of values and you writing that entire list as single value. CSV is text only so it is getting quoted. You will need to iterate over `measurements` and add each element of the list as a separate item in the row.

Comment: On another note not sure how `0.0 mg/L` DO concentration gets to `50000.0%` DO saturation?

Comment: yeah the sensor is busted rn, replacement parts are on the way and the other sensors are currently in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified version of what you are doing that should work:

```
import csv
from from datetime import datetime 

column_headers = ["Timestamp","DO Concentration (mg/L)","DO Saturation (%)","Temperature (�C)","Pressure (kPa)","DO Salinity (mg/L)"]

measurements = [[0.0, 50000.0, 26.399999618530273, 100.69999694824219, 50.0], [0.0, 50000.0, 26.399999618530273, 100.69999694824219, 50.0]]

with open('sensor_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as my_data_file:   
    csv_writer = csv.writer(my_data_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(column_headers)
    for row in measurements:
        row_list = row
        row_list.insert(0, datetime.now())
        csv_writer.writerow(row_list)

cat sensor_data.csv 
Timestamp,DO Concentration (mg/L),DO Saturation (%),Temperature (�C),Pressure (kPa),DO Salinity (mg/L)
2022-11-23 11:04:38.843266,0.0,50000.0,26.399999618530273,100.69999694824219,50.0
2022-11-23 11:04:38.843319,0.0,50000.0,26.399999618530273,100.69999694824219,50.0
```

Realized you did not have to iterate over the values just prepend the timestamp to each measurement row and then write it out.

A modified version of your code. This assumes that `measurements` in `measurements = gdx.read()` is a list.

```
import csv
import os
import time
from gdx import gdx 
gdx = gdx.gdx()
gdx.open(connection='usb')   
gdx.select_sensors() 
os.chdir(r"C:\\Users\\")
with open('sensor_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as my_data_file:   
    csv_writer = csv.writer(my_data_file)
    while True:
        gdx.start(period=100) 
        column_headers = gdx.enabled_sensor_info()
        column_headers.insert(0, "Timestamp")
        csv_writer.writerow(column_headers)

        for i in range(0,100000):
            measurements = gdx.read()
            localtime = time.localtime()
            result = time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p", localtime)
            print(result)
            combined_rows = measurements.insert(0, result)
            csv_writer.writerow(combined_rows)
            print(combined_rows)
            my_data_file.flush()
            time.sleep(59.9)
```

Comment: column_headers = ["Timestamp","DO Concentration (mg/L)","DO Saturation (%)","Temperature (�C)","Pressure (kPa)","DO Salinity (mg/L)"]
        csv_writer.writerow(column_headers)
    
        for i in range(0,100000):
            measurements = gdx.read()
            for row in measurements:
                row_list = row
                row_list.insert(0, datetime.now())
                csv_writer.writerow(row_list)
                my_data_file.flush()
                time.sleep(59.9

Comment: is that what you meant, cause when i use csv in write mode it just overwrites it for me

Comment: it works on just the two lines in your example however i need it to work as part of the loop with the data collection which uses the gdx module sorry if thats a big ask

Comment: 1) For this example I used `with open('sensor_data.csv', 'w', newline='') ` you would need to change to `with open('sensor_data.csv', 'a', newline='')` to append, I figured that was obvious. 2) Just move this into your loop.

Comment: Updated answer with modified version of your code. Not tested, so verify it on your end.

Comment: thank you for your help, im not sure as to why but now its producing this error code Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\", line 14, in <module>
    column_headers.insert(0, "Timestamp")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'
PS C:\Users\Lhuth>

Comment: or alternatively  csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType when sensor is selected

Comment: The error messages tell you the issue: 1) ` 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert' ` means `column_headers` was set to `None` probably by ` gdx.enabled_sensor_info()`. You only want to run this once anyway, you don't want to append the column headers each time you append new data. 2) Again something was set to `None`, I'm guessing `combined_rows`.  You need to update your code to protect against invalid data, that is a general issue in all code.